# How to add copy button in gist?

Tags: gist

I need to add a copy button in gist code area like shown in the screenshot:
[image]

I've tried to ask chatgpt and search answer on Google, but it seems like no one asked this earlier. May be here someone knows how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible currently without external tools, since it cannot be done with just pure Markdown. This is something that GitHub should implement on their end, and for some reason they haven't implemented it for Gists, only for the main `github.com`.

However, consider using one of these external tools:

- https://github.com/zenorocha/codecopy
- https://github.com/Mottie/GitHub-userscripts/wiki/GitHub-copy-code-snippet

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'll try these extentions

Comment: It seems that `codecopy` is removed from at least Chrome webstore, but you can build a version for yourself with these steps: https://github.com/zenorocha/codecopy/issues/71#issuecomment-948381112